# Issues getting files from my friend to work on my eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

My friend sent me a project from his eclipse workspace for me to take a look at, however when I tried to put the folder in my workspace it did nothing.  I opened eclipse and nothing was there.  So i tried to make my own project and just put the .java and .class files in their respected folders, but it still didn't work.  Is there some special way I have to transfer them?  I should also mention he has a windows computer and I have a mac if that makes any difference for file types like that.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should just be able to go to File -> import -> existing project and select the folder which contains the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you can just take the .java files and paste them into your 'src' folder in a new eclipse project, you should have no issues. Just make sure you refresh your project in eclipse(right-click on project folder and click refresh, or click on it and hit f5).

Answer (score 0):

This is what i normally do.

Suppose your eclipse workspace is D:\EclipseWorkspace and your project name is Project1.
Then i would copy Project1 in eclipse workspace on disk to have D:\EclipseWorkspace\Project1.

Then create a new java project in eclipse and when prompted for name provide name as Project1 (exactly same) and say finish. It will import the project automatically. Everything should be up :)